# wxPythong - getting return value from wx.CallAfter?

Tags: python, multithreading, wxpython

When I call wx functions from a non-main thread I use wx.CallAfter, but what happens when I want to get the return value of the function called? What must I do then? Is it stored somewhere?

Comment: Why the -1? Was there something wrong with the question?

Comment: You might want to check [this](http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/return-value-from-wx-CallAfter-td2357569.html).